# "Uniformly random" distribution of 2D points over given time

Tags: algorithm, math, random, geometry, shuffle

I am looking for an optimal algorithm to solve the following problem:

On a two-dimensional plane, a set of ***N*** points with X and Y coordinates is given. These points need to be "lit" during a cycle of length ***t*** in such a way that for each discrete step of length ***t/N***, one point is "lit". The distribution of points by steps should not be truly random, but look "uniformly random" to a person. Thus, each taken several points in a row should be at a sufficient distance from each other.

At the moment, I propose to implement the following algorithm:

1. Divide the plane into several regions with a (different) number of points.
2. Fill each of them with "fake" points up to the number of ***N***.
3. Each of the regions is then shuffled using Fisher-Yates.
4. Then the shuffled points of each region are evenly distributed over time ***t*** with ***N*** steps.
5. Then, for each step, we take one point from each region in random order, discarding the "fake" ones and adding the existing ones to the ordered array.
6. The position of the point in the resulting array is the desired step number.

Will this approach lead to a distribution that will seem "randomly uniform" to people? Perhaps there is a simpler implementation? Markov chains? Something like dithering?

Comment: Why not shuffle point indices and light them on in shuffled order?

Comment: I would create a list of unlit and lit points ... and on each time step randomly transfer point from unlit to lit list ...

Comment: @MBo if we take points in random order, then there will be clustering, and some steps in a row will "light" nearby points. That's what the current truly random algorithm does and what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Spektre The distribution of points by steps should not be truly random, but look "uniformly random" to a person. Thus, each taken several points in a row should be at a sufficient distance from each other.

Comment: what would you do with (say) a cluster of 6 points and a cluster of 2 points?

Comment: @AakashM I would treat these clusters as two regions, so I would evenly distribute 6 points within a cycle in random order, and the same for two points. Then I would add a random offset for both regions (moving the points outside the cycle to the beginning) and merge them. Almost like in this article: http://keyj.emphy.de/balanced-shuffle/. But I wonder if there is a more appropriate and efficient algorithm.

Comment: However, this algorithm has a drawback: close points on the edges of regions may occur to be close in time, and also points within each region

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.